# iOS 17 (possibly) has broken OpenDNS filtering

Tags: iphone, ipad, dns

I have a private server running on my home network that gives out DHCP addresses and uses OpenDNS as a DNS server so I can use its content fitering.

AFAIK it's always worked OK, but I've noticed today that if I go to a site that should be blocked on both my iPhone and iPad the page loads. Both Safari and Firefox show this problem. It's possible this is connected to having been upgraded to iOS 17, but I don't check this kind of thing regularly so that might be a complete red herring.

Here is the weird part:

If I load a page I can see in the logs of my DNS server that it's returning the corrrect address (146.112.61.106 is the OpenDNS blocked site landing page):

```
Oct  2 11:32:57 dnsmasq[29667]: query[A] vnt.xhamster.com from 192.168.10.215
Oct  2 11:32:57 dnsmasq[29667]: forwarded vnt.xhamster.com to 208.67.220.220
Oct  2 11:32:57 dnsmasq[29667]: reply vnt.xhamster.com is 146.112.61.106
```

If I check the DNS entry on my phone using something like the Ping Tool app, I also consistently get a result that matches the IP address above.

So, where is my browser getting the correct IP address from? I have Apple Private Relay turned off, as that's known to interfere with these things. By default, "Limit IP Address Tracking" is on (it's not clear to me what the difference is between this setting and the APR one), but even if I turn it off I get the same problem. Sometimes, the block works so it seems intermittent.

Where else can I look to see where iOS is getting the correct IP address from for these sites?

To add; blocking still works fine on my laptop (Windows 11), and all OpenDNS tests suggest blocking is configured correctly, e.g. visiting [internetbadguys.com](https://internetbadguys.com).

Update: Issue seems to have been resolved in iOS 17.4.

Comment: Reported to OpenDNS and is with their 2nd/3rd line. No updates for a while though. https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/19706685053076-Blocking-not-working-on-iPhone-since-iOS-17-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have been fixed in iOS 17.4.